# WP7 - ignore listbox scroll inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app I have something similar to this layout

> Grid
>
> > Grid with stuff in
> >       Grid with stuff in
> >       LongListSelector

Now the 2 grids with stuff in take up most of the screen so the LongListSelector only really allows you to scroll an item at a time.

I then modified layout to include a scrollviewer

> ScrollViewer
>
> > Grid
> >     Grid with stuff in
> >       Grid with stuff in
> >       LongListSelector

Obviously once you scroll to the LongListSelector and then try to scroll more you end up scrolling within the LongListSelector. Is there anyway I can ignore the scrolling in the LongListSelector and also have the listbox resize to match its contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the scrollviewer and change your layout as follows:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ListHeader">
   ... your grids ....
   </DataTemplate>


   <toolkit:LongListSelector  
      ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListHeader}" >
```

This adds the grids to the top of the `LongListSelector`, which is the functionality you want if I understand you correctly.

Comment: don't worry, that happens to the best :)